# creating a service broker contract permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, nservicebus, service-broker

I'm trying to create a contract in sql for pushing messages out from sql onto nservicebus (msmq) queues although I'm getting the following error message when executing this code!  any ideas why I get this?
Thanks,
james

```
CREATE CONTRACT [NServiceBusSendMessageContract] 
(
    [NServiceBusSendMessage] SENT BY ANY 
)

Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the message type 'NServiceBusSendMessage', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: Can we assume that you mean SQL Server Service Broker?

Comment: thank you, yes it is for the SQL service broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done this?

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [NServiceBusSendMessage]
    VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML
```

Comment: no.  just tried now and it 'completed successfully' but when expanding the contracts folder I cannot see any entries..?  thanks,

Comment: yup definitely, right clicking on the database - new window, executing the query then expanding the window explorer for that database and I cannot see anything within the Server Broker/Contracts folder :(

Comment: oh sorry, this query above creates a message successfully in the message folder.  But I'm trying to see how to create a contract?  thanks

Comment: So once you create the message you still can't create the contract?

Comment: I now have a contract thank you.  I need to work out what I can do with it. thanks,

Comment: James, I would be very interested in your final solution - it would be very beneficial for us to be able to consume service broker messages directly on an nservicebus input queue. Would be grateful if you could outline how you did it? At present we're using biztalk as an intermediary but would love to remove it from the soltution. Many thanks